# When should I add multiple answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, multiple-answers

I recently asked and self-answered a question on main [What was the first arcade game to use a microprocessor instead of discrete logic?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/613/621)

In the comments, discussion started on what the definition of "discrete logic" and "microprocessors" are.  Having left the question open ended, the line is quite fuzzy.  I initially answered the question drawing the line between TI 74XX series of integrated circuits and an 8-bit microprocessor like Intel's 8080.  Since then, there has been discussion of additional chips meeting the "microprocessor" criteria.  Acknowledging this, I added an additional answer of a game that technically pre-dates Gun Fight and the explanation in my first answer.

In this case, were two answers appropriate?  Should I have consolidated the second (newer) answer into my first answer?  When is it appropriate to provide multiple answers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think in this case it's a rare occasion where two answers from one person do make sense as they tackle the subject in different ways, but they could easily be rolled together into one.

A good reason to keep them separate in this case is that one answer has been accepted and upvoted a lot more than the other: it's allowing the community to come to consensus on which of the two has more merit, which wouldn't happen if they were joined.

Answer (score 4):

It is worth looking at the long-standing advice on Meta.SE  [What is the official etiquette on answering a question twice?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice)  and more recently [Is it OK to post multiple answers to a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60445/is-it-ok-to-post-multiple-answers-to-a-question) .

In summary, if you have two different answers to a question, post them separately.  The community will select the better one by voting.

If you have just a variation to add to an existing answer then edit your existing answer.  This would apply even if the existing answer is accepted and upvoted.

I would say that, in your cited example question, two answers is the correct approach.